# C programming, atoi function

Tags: c

In C programming, I'm really confused with the atoi function. 
I can also write like this:
 `atoi(years) = age;` 
instead of :

`age = atoi(years);`.

The first one gives a warning but still work like the second. Which one is right?

Comment: The second is right; the first shouldn’t compile

Comment: What would the first one achieve if it could compile at all? And how is it specific to `atoi`?

Comment: In C, the assignment operator assigns from right to left.

Comment: _"The first one gives a warning..._": would be interesting to hear _which_ warning you get.

Comment: If what you say is true (it compiles and works the same either way), you need to throw away that compiler.  My guess is that it never produced an executable, and you just re-ran the old one.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are (mistakenly) using those as conditions? Like in `if (age = atoi(years)) ...`(wrong) instead of `if (atoi(years) == age)...`

Comment: @Bob__ That would give a bit more sense to the question...

Comment: C is not a language to learn by trial and error.  Any introductory book, class, or tutorial on C would tell you that in an assignment, the value on the *right* gets assigned to the thing on the *left*.  Please read one of those books or tutorials, or take one of those classes.  It will take a bit more time up-front, but it will make the rest of the learning process much easier and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, with `atoi` or any other function. If a C compiler allows this and generates code to assign from `atoi(years)` to `age`, the compiler is broken.

For fun I put this into a little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
  {
  char *years = "61";
  int age;

  atoi(years) = age;

  printf("%d\n", age);
  }
```

and jammed it through my local C compiler (HP C/aC++ compiler FWIW). The following messages were produced:

```
$ cc test.c

"test.c", line 9: error #2137: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
    atoi(years) = age;
    ^

"test.c", line 9: warning #2549-D: variable "age" is used before its value is
          set
    atoi(years) = age;
                  ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "test.c".
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

In C programming, the assignment operator assigns from right to left. So the first one will throw a warning.

Second one is the right format to do so.